# Cannot insert degree character (°) through OCI

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter with OCI10 driver and I have a problem inserting the degree character  (°) into database when **using binding**.
However the error message is empty

```
Message: Query ' INSERT INTO T1 (ID, TEXT) VALUES (1, 'text with °') ' was not executed; returned error: ''.
```

When I use SQL Relay or insert manualy with SQL Developer, it's wokring fine.
Also when I don't use the binding, it is inserted correctly.

Comment: check the character encoding

Comment: always and everywhere? maybe you need to explicitly set the character encoding when establishing the connection

Comment: What happens when you try it like this: `INSERT INTO T1 (ID, TEXT) VALUES (1, 'text with ' || chr(176))` ?

Comment: that chr() function is working... but I would have to run some replace function on all my queries, because I never know where it'll appear...

Comment: What CI version are you using? Also have you seen if any other chars are causing the same problem?

Comment: CodeIgniter 2.0.2
so far I didn't get any other characters causing this problem... the inputs are mostly plain text, but theoreticaly can contain any character

Comment: Are you sure your source file is in UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

$this->db->db_set_charset('latin1', 'latin1_swedish_ci');
Use this while inserting record